# SEAM, JSF Image manipulation

Tags: java, image, jsf, seam

I am new to SEAM and JSF, and want to design image manipulation application using it. I am planning to use JQuery plugins at client side for image effects such as crop, rotate, resize and many more. My Concerns are,

1. I don't know about any good server-side library for this. Which would be a best for java.
2. How Clientside and Serverside manipulation will be synchronized, because if user decide to crop image at client-side, how serverside library would have information about coordinates to crop?

If you guys have any different approach than this, it would be good to learn.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using JCrop and other JQuery plugins and using Java ImageIO at server side. JCrop works pretty much with coordinates.